# Studio Debugger Error App is still running

Tags: visual-studio, debugging

when I'm trying to debug my app to ARM Machine, I got this error :

[image]

I try this :

https://codedocu.com/Net-Framework/Windows-Store/Bridge/Erros/Error--Problem--Log_colon_-Unable-to-activate-Windows-Store-App----delete-older-VCLibs?1980

but the problem is still exiting.
I also created a developer account and got the licence but no effect.

Comment: What is the machine you are using, pad or phone? If you are using pad, you should select x86 or x64.

Comment: I use a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B vi 2 with Windows IOT : v.10.0.17134.165